# FluentApi IsRequired ignored by PostMan

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, model

I am developing a set of WebAPI.
If I define my model using DataAnnotation:

```
public Prat()
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Pratica { get; set; }
    public int Anno { get; set; }
}
```

When I send a POST (using Postman) like this:

```
{
  "pratica": "",
  "anno": 2000,
}
```

I got this error, as expected

```
{
  "Pratica": [
    "The Pratica field is required."
  ]
}
```

But, if I use FluentApi instead of DataAnnotation:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Prat>(entity =>
            {entity.Property(e => e.Pratica)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(10)")}
}
```

the validation is not performed.
Why?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is because Data Annotation is performing both validation and mapping whereas FluentAPI is only responsible for mapping.

[See this answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9310435/5857401)